# For what values of $\alpha > 0$ the equation $p(x) = x^3-9x^2+26x-\alpha =0$ has three positive real roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> For what values of $\alpha > 0$ the equation $p(x) = x^3-9x^2+26x-\alpha =0$ has three positive real roots?
>
> The options given are as follows :
>
> $(A)$ $\alpha \ge 27$
>
> $(B)$ $\alpha > 81$
>
> $(C)$ $27 < \alpha <81$
>
> $(D)$ $54 < \alpha \le 81$

What I have tried is that I first transform the equation to the form $y^3 + 3Hy + G = 0$ and then I have applied the fact that this equation has three positive real roots if $G^2 + 4H^3 < 0$.Here I found $G = 24 - \alpha$ and $H = -\frac {1} {3}$ and then calculating we get $\alpha \in (24-\frac {2 {\sqrt 3}} {9} , 24 + \frac {2 {\sqrt 3}} {9})$ which is not similar to any of the given options.Please help me in finding the right option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try applying Descartes' rule of signs?

Comment: Yeah it gives me the above equation has no negative solution and at most three positive solutions.Then what I will do?

Comment: The question is tagged algebra-precalculus. Does that mean that the derivative is not an available tool?

Comment: yeah @HaraldHanche-Olsen you can solve it using calculus also.Actually I dont find suitable tag for it>So I had to opt it.Please edit tags if anybody wants more appropiate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the roots are $a$,$b$, $c$.

Consider
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ac)x-abc$$
So
$$ab+bc+ac=26,\alpha=abc$$
By AM-GM inequality
$$\sqrt[3]{ab\cdot bc\cdot ac}\le\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3}\implies\alpha^{2/3}\le\frac{26}3<9\implies\alpha<27$$

So no options are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I plotted the graph with desmos. I think you are correct.

We can also solve the problem by calculus.

$p'(x)=3x^2-18x+26$ and $p''(x)=6x-18$.

When $x=3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $p'(x)=0$ and $p''(x)>0$.

When $x=3-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $p'(x)=0$ and $p''(x)<0$.

$p(x)$ attains its maximum when $x=3-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and its minimum when $x=3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

$p(x)=0$ has $3$ positive roots if

(1) $p(3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})<0$,

(2) $p(3-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})>0$, and

(3) $p(0)<0$ (this is true whenever (2) is true).